# Python: unlimited loops in a loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, data-science

Is there a smart way to get our of unlimited level nested loop?

At each loop it has to check if `item` isn't already in `done_items` list or `group` isn't already in `done_groups` list. If not, then another loop starts. An so on, and so on... In most of occastions 2 levels are enough but sometimes it requires up to 100.

```py
def get_cluster(dict_1, dict_2):

    done_groups, done_items = [], []
    item_cluster = {}
    cluster = 1

    for item_main in dict_1.keys():
        if item_main not in done_items:  # check if item hasn't been already done
            for group_1 in dict_1[item_main]:  # Loop 1 through groups
                if group_1 not in done_groups:  # check if group hasn't been already done
                    done_groups.append(group_1)
                    for item_1 in dict_2[group_1]:  # Loop 1 through items
                        if item_1 not in done_items:  # check if item hasn't been already done
                            done_items.append(item_1)
                            item_cluster[item_1] = cluster
                            for group_2 in dict_1[item_1]:  # Loop 2 through groups
                                if group_2 not in done_groups:  # check if group hasn't been already done
                                    done_groups.append(group_2)
                                    for item_2 in dict_2[group_2]:  # Loop 2 through items
                                        if item_2 not in done_items:  # check if item hasn't been already done
                                            done_items.append(item_2)
                                            item_cluster[item_2] = cluster
                                            for group_3 in dict_1[item_2]:  # Loop 3 through groups
                                                if group_3 not in done_groups:  # check if group hasn't been already done
                                                    done_groups.append(group_3)
                                                    for item_3 in dict_2[group_3]:  # Loop 3 through items
                                                        if item_3 not in done_items:  # check if item hasn't been already done
                                                            done_items.append(item_3)
                                                            item_cluster[item_3] = cluster
            cluster += 1

    return item_cluster
```

Is there a way to apply `while` loop here?

Comment: Can you share the structure of dict_1 and dict_2 that you pass to this function?

Comment: I think this is a prime example for recursion. Do your really need to do this with loops? Maybe write a class that can traverse your object tree?

Comment: Can you provide example dictionaries? The best method is to do something like While "Variable True" do this until a condition is met then set the Variable to be False and break

Comment: Have you tried to solve this recursively?

Comment: dictionaries have same set of data, but from 2 perspectives, like:
dict_1 = {1: ['A', 'C'], 2: ['B', 'E'], 3: ['D'], 4: ['A', 'F'], 5: ['A', 'C'], 6: ['C'], 7: ['B'], 8: ['F'], 9: ['B', 'D'], 10: ['E']}
dict_2 = {'A': [1, 4, 5], 'B': [2, 7, 9], 'C': [1, 5, 6], 'D': [3, 9], 'E': [2, 10], 'F': [4, 8]}

Comment: Can you explain in other words, what exactly you are trying to achieve? So not what you are doing, but rather what you result is? I think that would help a lot in coming up with different approaches

Comment: I'll try recurtion, thanks!

Comment: @LeoE I must group all items and groups into separate clusters which don't overlap one another.

Comment: Looks like a graph traversal to me. You can do that either with recursion, or with a stack (depth-first) or queue (breadth-first).

Comment: I agree with Thomas. Explain what your function is supposed to *do*.

Comment: lol what is going on here

Comment: Can you show a result when applying it to the two dicts you showed earlier? I still have problems with understanding what the goal is, what do you mean by non overlapping?